# android support-v7-appcomat compiling issue

Tags: android, adt, android-support-library

after I updated `Android SDK Tools` and `ADT` to `22.6`, I found a error in `android-support-v7-appcompat`(I created a project for `Android`support class):

```
android-support-v7-appcompat] Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 16
```

So I am wondering how to fix it and will it affect projects which use the support class before the update.

thx

Comment: you need to install new android api. kitkat is level 19 [see here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html). or as @blackbelt said user other java version

Comment: @isi I have already installed `API19` in `SDK manager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import this library from you Android ADT Bundle.

/Eclipse Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/extras/android/support/v7

Use this library in the Android Project. The issue will be FIX.

Note : You need to locate your V7 library from your Android ADT

Hope this helps